# XML to LINQ with Digg API

Tags: xml, linq, api, digg

Continuining from my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817619/unknown-error-using-digg-api-and-uri-handler-silverlight, which I want to thank you for answering) I now have a follow up less errory question.

To extract the data from [this](http://services.digg.com/1.0/story.getAll?count=10&topic=lifestyle) we got the following XML to LINQ code.

```
    var stories = from story in document.Descendants("story")
                  //where story.Element("thumbnail") != null
                  select new DiggStory
                  {
                      Id = (string)story.Attribute("story_id"),
                      Title = (string)story.Element("title"),
                      Description = (string)story.Element("description"),
                      ThumbNail = (string)story.Element("thumbnail").Attribute("src"),
                      //HrefLink = (string)story.Attribute("permalink"),
                      NumDiggs = (int)story.Attribute("diggs")
                  };
```

This works as intended, but seeing as the Digg API is outdated I would prefer to be the new api, which creates [the following XML file](http://services.digg.com/2.0/story.getTopNews?limit=10&type=xml&topic=gaming).

Now I was wondering how do I adjust the XML to LINQ code to utilize this new XML file?
I know the problem is in

```
   var stories = from story in document.Descendants("story")
```

But I do not know what I need to change it to, because the [new XML file](http://services.digg.com/2.0/story.getTopNews?limit=10&type=xml&topic=gaming) has more levels. I was thinking something in the line of

```
var stories = from item in document.Descendants("stories")
```

But that doesn't seem work.

I want to thank you again for helping me with this problem and any further problems, this is truly a great website!

Thank you, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:

```
var stories = from item in document.RootElement.Element("stories").Descendants("item")
              select new DiggStory
              {
                  Id = item.Element("story_id").Value
                  // ...etc
              }
```

You can learn more about parsing XML documents with [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).  Of particular use to you is probably the [XElement documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx), which shows all the methods and properties defined for each "element" (tag) in the XML document.